# Doing combination of row entries in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv with data similar to

```
a,b
b,c
c,d
```

I am working on a script which does combination (math) operation on this list taking input from each row and printing it to stdout. like below

```
a,b;b,c
a,b;c,d
b,c;c,d
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
import sys
from itertools import combinations
with open('d.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
opencsv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in opencsv:
    result = ', '.join(row)
    print type(result)
    combine = combinations([row], 4)
    print combine
    for i in list(combine):
        print i
```

I dont want the reverse occurance of the combination like, `a,b;b,c` and `b,c;a,b` in the output. I was following the steps written here (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/) but I think it only works if the list have single entries and not double.

Can someone help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: csv is short for "comma separated values" so the fact that you want to read the whole line "a,b" as a single item is unusual. Maybe you should just use readlines() instead of a csvreader.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Why are you doing this result thing ?

```
import csv
import sys
import sys
from itertools import combinations
f = open("d.csv", 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    combine = combinations(row, 2)
    for i in list(combine):
        print i
```

Comment: I was following this steps in this blog (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/). I was just trying. I thought `import combinations` is a module which does all this. Sorry if I am wrong. I am still learning. @FallAndLearn

Comment: You have to do import combinations. Update your for loop with mine and check.

Comment: Nothing is happening. Not printing `i`

Comment: First check are you able to get the row from csv ?. As I think you have placed delimiter as '  '

Comment: I am placing delimiter as `deimiter = ' '`.Should it be `,`?  The `row` is printing, but `i` is not printing. The row is printing like this `[a,b]`

Comment: see the updated answer.. i have tested on my machine.. it is giving the right output

Comment: also for your given csv, with combination length as 2 you will get the same number of combinations as your input.

Comment: you can accept my answer if it got your problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do three different things all at once. Because you have having trouble, it follows that you should split them up into separate tasks, and figure out each part.

First, you want to read the csv file in an unusual way.
Second, you want to take combinations.
Third, you want to print each combination in an unusual way.

I think that your combinations are working fine, but you are not getting the inputs to it that you expected. In order to get the combinations you say you want from the input file you showed, I do not understand why you are using a space as the delimiter. You showed the full row being taken as one string, therefore I think you want delimiter='\n'. Because you then want to take combinations of those rows, I don't think you want them nested inside another list, so I just took row[0] for each row, which is already exactly 1 item, due to the delimiter of '\n'. At this point, I don't know if you need to check for len(row) or handle an exception, but it might not be an issue anyway. I'll leave error handling to you.

Having set up the input, we get something nice from combinations, and then it's easy to convert to the desired output with string.join(';')

```
import sys
import csv
import string
from itertools import combinations

def get_rows(filename):            
    with open(filename) as f:
        # may need to check or catch index out of range
        return [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\n')]

def get_pairs(rows):
    return [c for c in combinations(rows, 2)]

def print_combinations(list_of_combinations):
    for c in list_of_combinations:
        print string.join(c, sep=';')

print_combinations(get_pairs(get_rows('d.csv')))
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for this detailed explanation. This function wise split code works good. Splitting the task into different functions makes it easier. This was a very nice learning. 
So based on what I understand from the code
[1]First it reads the csv file from print_combination function
[2]Next each line of the file it delimits by \n
[3]Gets first pars and takes the next pair from get_row function
[4]Sends it to print_combination function to seperate it with ;

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: close -- get_rows reads the csv file and returns a list of rows, by using \n delimiter